# builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true) does not work

Tags: android, background, android-alertdialog

I have in my code setInverseBackgroundForced set to true, but it doesn't appear to work. The code produces white text on a dark background.

Here is my builder code:

```
public class test {
    private void createMyLocationDisabledAlert() {
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
          builder.setTitle("Title")
            .setInverseBackgroundForced(true)
            .setMessage(
                      "my message")
                      .setCancelable(false)
                      .setPositiveButton("Options",
                              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                              showOptions();
                          }
                      });
          builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     dialog.cancel();
                 }
            });
          AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
          alert.show();
     }
}
```

What could I be doing wrong? I have tried the method call in different positions of the code block but to no resolve.

Answer (score 2):

**setInverseBackgroundForced (boolean useInverseBackground)** is deprecated in Android API level 23 (Android 6.0 Marshmallow).

This flag is only used for pre-Material themes. Instead, specify the window background using on the alert dialog theme.

Code is like this!

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseActivity.this, R.style.Dark2).create();
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.background_dark);
```

Answer (score 0):

User a custom dialog class extending DialogFragment and use it to show the AlertDialog.

Example:

```
public class CustomAlertDialog extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Title")
            .setInverseBackgroundForced(true)
            .setMessage("my message")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(
                "Options",
                 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     showOptions();
                 }
            });
        builder.setNegativeButton(
            "Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        return alert;
    }
}

public class test {
    private void createMyLocationDisabledAlert() {
        new CustomAlertDialog().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), Constants.FragmentTagSearch);
    }
}
```

Note: I was using the support library for compatibility, hence the use of `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score 0):

I too face the same problem today. And as things stand today, the Android doc says that `setInverseBackgroundForced()` API is deprecated and recommends the developer to specify the window background using the alert dialog theme.

Note: Deprecation ideally should not stop the functionality from working.

That said, I did't want to investigate as to why it is not working today and shifted my focus to get things done the cleaner and recommended way per Android docs. And it is something like the code below:

```
private final int DIALOG_THEME_STYLE = android.support.v7.appcompat.R.style.Base_Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_MinWidth;

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, DIALOG_THEME_STYLE);
```

Hope that helps!